# How to receive a JSON string in C?

Tags: c, json

I am trying to develop a socket client program in C language that will receive a JSON string from server.

How to implement the receiving side of the JSON data?

Is the JSON string will be received as character by character in client socket side?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that you could is to use some JSON API like for example Jansson. You can follow this link for documentation.

[Jansson API Documentation](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.9/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks .One more thing. Can I parse a Json string to c structure directly. Is there any specific api for this purpose

Comment: This Jansson API i think that doesnt allow you to do this. And i think is quite difficult.